# key sensitivity in html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to know how long a mouse/key was pressed before it was released so the response would be dependent on the key/mouse press.

For example, I have tried this but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

```
var time = new Date();
var mousedown, mouseup, mousehold;

document.addEventListener('onmousedown', function(){
    mousedown = time.getTime(); //gets time when mouse was pressed
});

document.addEventListener('onmouseup', function(){
    mouseup = time.getTime(); //time when mouse was released
    mousehold = mouseup - mousedown; //time difference
    console.log(mousehold);
});
```

Comment: Thanks(Comment removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should use

```
document.addEventListenter("mousedown", function() {...});
```

and

```
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {...}); '
```

Secondly, your `time.getTime` will get the time of the `time` variable. 
You should do this:

```js
var mousedown, mouseup, mousehold;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    mousedown = Date.now(); //gets time when mouse was pressed
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    mouseup = Date.now(); //time when mouse was released
    mousehold = mouseup - mousedown; //time difference
    console.log(mousehold);
});
```

Here is a better version:

```js
var mouseup, mousehold;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    mousedown = Date.now(); //gets time when mouse was pressed
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    mousehold = Date.now()- mousedown; //time difference
    console.log(mousehold);
});
```

There is no use of the mouseup variable if you just want to calculate the mousehold variable.

Comment: For the 2nd version, did you mean to declare mousedown instead of mouseup? Or it was intended?